# CSS clip-path with border-radius and box-shadow

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to code this card in a responsive manner, but I cannot get it to work.[image: custom card]

I've also tried using the exported SVG as background and as a :before element, but for dynamic content height it's just not good.

Then I've tried CSS clip-paths, but couldn't get rounded borders and the slight box-shadow to work.

Here's the code:

```css
.shaped-card {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  position: relative;
  background: #FBF2E2;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipped);
  clip-path: url(#clipped)
}
```

```html
<div class="shaped-card">
  <h2>Awesome headline</h2>
  <p>The best Lorem Ipsum Generator in all the sea! Heave this scurvy copyfiller fer yar next adventure and cajol yar clients into walking the plank with ev'ry layout! Configure above, then get yer pirate ipsum...own the high seas, arg!</p>
</div>

<!-- SVG use for clip-path reference -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="474.949" height="508.807" viewBox="0 0 474.949 508.807">
      <clipPath id="clipped"><path id="Path_64" data-name="Path 64" d="M6.323,508.807h462.3c3.492,0,6.323-4.324,6.323-9.658V9.658c0-5.334-2.831-9.658-6.323-9.658L6.323,41.518C2.831,41.518,0,45.842,0,51.177V499.148C0,504.482,2.831,508.807,6.323,508.807Z" transform="translate(474.949 508.807) rotate(180)" fill="none"/>
      </clipPath>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Updated the question with the path

Comment: What do you mean by responsive? How is the appearance of this supposed to change according to device/ viewport size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an `svg`, make its size and the element size matching, but `box-shadow` will not show while being cut off from `clip-path`.

What you can do is use `filter` from a transparent parent, see [`drop-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow):

possible example:

```css
.shaped-card {
  width: 475px;
  height:510px;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  position: relative;
  background:tomato;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipped);
  clip-path: url(#clipped);
  }
  section {
  filter:drop-shadow(0 0  5px #000);
}
svg {
position:absolute;right:100vw;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="474.949" height="508.807" viewBox="0 0 474.949 508.807">
  <clipPath id="clipped"><path id="Path_64" data-name="Path 64" d="M6.323,508.807h462.3c3.492,0,6.323-4.324,6.323-9.658V9.658c0-5.334-2.831-9.658-6.323-9.658L6.323,41.518C2.831,41.518,0,45.842,0,51.177V499.148C0,504.482,2.831,508.807,6.323,508.807Z" transform="translate(474.949 508.807) rotate(180)" fill="none"/>
  </clipPath>
</svg>
<section>
<div class="shaped-card">
  <h2>Awesome headline</h2>
  <p>The best Lorem Ipsum Generator in all the sea! Heave this scurvy copyfiller fer yar next adventure and cajol yar clients into walking the plank with ev'ry layout! Configure above, then get yer pirate ipsum...own the high seas, arg!</p>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to do it is using `skewY` with background color and border radius as follow :

```css
.shaped-card {
    width: 20%;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    background: #FBF2E2;
}
.shaped-card::before {
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 24px rgba(0,0,0,0.16);
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.shaped-card::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background: #FBF2E2;
    transform: skewY(10deg);
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 24px rgba(0,0,0,0.16);
}
```

```html
<div class="shaped-card">
  <h2>Awesome headline</h2>
  <p>The best Lorem Ipsum Generator in all the sea! Heave this scurvy copyfiller fer yar next adventure and cajol yar clients into walking the plank with ev'ry layout! Configure above, then get yer pirate ipsum...own the high seas, arg!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I've thought of this but discarded the idea because setting up a proper box-shadow on this seemed impossible. Is it not?

Comment: can you give me example of box shadow you are trying to apply ?

Comment: A simple box-shadow to the whole card. Even with an additional pseudo-element, it still looks off in the middle. https://codepen.io/simii/pen/bGpZwEO

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to create this shape using css clip path with responsive for dynamic content height & width. Just we need that shape svg file and online svg path to css clip path [maker](https://www.plantcss.com/).

```css
.shape_parent
{
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 12px #b1b1b1);
    padding: 1rem;
}

.shape_area
{ 
  width:100%;
  min-height: 635.9px;
  clip-path: polygon(calc(100% - 11px) calc(100% - 0.10000000000002px), 9px calc(100% - 60px), 9px calc(100% - 60px), 7.5087px calc(100% - 60.261px), 6.1056px calc(100% - 60.732px), 4.8069px calc(100% - 61.395px), 3.6288px calc(100% - 62.232px), 2.5875px calc(100% - 63.225px), 1.6992px calc(100% - 64.356px), 0.9801px calc(100% - 65.607px), 0.4464px calc(100% - 66.96px), 0.1143px calc(100% - 68.397px), 1.4421363423572E-31px calc(100% - 69.9px), 0px 10px, 0px 10px, 0.1315px 8.3835px, 0.512px 6.848px, 1.1205px 5.4145px, 1.936px 4.104px, 2.9375px 2.9375px, 4.104px 1.936px, 5.4145px 1.1205px, 6.848px 0.512px, 8.3835px 0.1315px, 10px 1.6640034719506E-31px, calc(100% - 10px) 0px, calc(100% - 10px) 0px, calc(100% - 8.3834999999999px) 0.1315px, calc(100% - 6.8479999999998px) 0.512px, calc(100% - 5.4145px) 1.1205px, calc(100% - 4.1039999999999px) 1.936px, calc(100% - 2.9375px) 2.9375px, calc(100% - 1.9359999999999px) 4.104px, calc(100% - 1.1205px) 5.4145px, calc(100% - 0.51199999999994px) 6.848px, calc(100% - 0.13149999999996px) 8.3835px, calc(100% - 1.1368683772162E-13px) 10px, calc(100% - 0px) calc(100% - 10px), calc(100% - 0px) calc(100% - 10px), calc(100% - 0.14869999999985px) calc(100% - 8.2701999999998px), calc(100% - 0.57759999999973px) calc(100% - 6.6375999999998px), calc(100% - 1.2609px) calc(100% - 5.1274px), calc(100% - 2.1728000000001px) calc(100% - 3.7648px), calc(100% - 3.2875px) calc(100% - 2.575px), calc(100% - 4.5792px) calc(100% - 1.5831999999999px), calc(100% - 6.0221px) calc(100% - 0.81460000000004px), calc(100% - 7.5904px) calc(100% - 0.2944px), calc(100% - 9.2583px) calc(100% - 0.047800000000052px), calc(100% - 11px) calc(100% - 0.10000000000014px)); 
  background-color: #FBF1E2;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape_parent">
  <div class="shape_area"></div>
</div>
```