# Multiple box shadows on clipped path

Tags: css

```css
.box-shadow {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/sJL6EDG.jpeg) no-repeat 50%/cover;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px red,0 0 0 12px #fff,0 0 0 14px red,0 0 0 24px #fff,0 0 0 26px red,0 0 0 36px #fff,0 0 0 38px red,0 0 0 48px #fff,0 0 0 50px red,0 0 0 60px #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px red,0 0 0 12px #fff,0 0 0 14px red,0 0 0 24px #fff,0 0 0 26px red,0 0 0 36px #fff,0 0 0 38px red,0 0 0 48px #fff,0 0 0 50px red,0 0 0 60px #fff;
  height: 530px;
  margin: 100px;
  position: relative;
  width: 477px
}

.clip-path {
  clip-path: path("M444.248 108.547L271.254 8.76755C250.987 -2.92252 226.016 -2.92252 205.748 8.76755L32.7544 108.547C12.487 120.237 0 141.84 0 165.22V364.779C0 388.159 12.487 409.763 32.7544 421.453L205.748 521.232C226.016 532.923 250.987 532.923 271.254 521.232L444.248 421.453C464.516 409.763 477 388.159 477 364.779V165.22C477 141.84 464.516 120.237 444.248 108.547Z");
}
```

```html
<div class="box-shadow"></div>
<div class="box-shadow clip-path"></div>
```

Any alternatives to achieve the same box-shadow (or similar) behaviour in 2 that is achieved in 1? Any other alternatives (even non-CSS) are welcome

Comment: Because you have used clip-path, and it masks everything of the shape and hide all the details overflowing that mask.

Comment: I know why it happens, I'm looking for a solution that would achieve what I want, I can think of several ones, including masking and using drop-shadow on a bunch of extra elements that are incrementally scaled up.

Comment: @Ravenous so you want to achive it with one element? or multiple elemets are good?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64067762/css-clip-path-with-border-radius-and-box-shadow may be this will help

Comment: @Sarkar, anything will do

Comment: @Ravenous IMHO I don't think an easy solution is possible, especially because the hexagon is uneven and with curved angles. If this direction is a must, then create hexagon paths that act as the box shadows from the first image. I would try it to put the image inside an svg and wrap that in paths so that the image view size is controlled.

Answer (score 0):

I went with sth similar to the snippet below, it's far from perfect, but it does the job and is easy to scale via SCSS.

```scss
@for $i from 2 through 12 {
  &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    bottom: -#{16 * $i}px;
    right: -#{16 * $i}px;
    height: calc(530px + #{16 * 2 * $i}px);
    width: calc(477px + #{16 * 2 * $i}px);
  }
}
```

```css
.workaround {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative
}

.workaround>div {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="611" height="658" viewBox="0 0 611 658" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M305.603 656.757C278.424 656.757 251.452 649.553 227.979 635.97L78.4972 549.734C30.5229 522.155 0.873535 470.496 0.873535 415.133V242.661C0.873535 187.298 30.7288 135.845 78.4972 108.06L227.773 21.8244C251.452 8.24075 278.219 1.03729 305.397 1.03729C332.576 1.03729 359.548 8.24075 383.021 21.8244L532.297 108.06C580.271 135.639 609.921 187.298 609.921 242.661V415.133C609.921 470.496 580.066 521.949 532.297 549.734L383.227 635.97C359.548 649.553 332.782 656.757 305.603 656.757Z" stroke="red" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/></svg>');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 530px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 477px
}

.workaround>div.img {
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/sJL6EDG.jpeg) no-repeat 50%/cover;
    bottom: 0;
    -webkit-clip-path: path("M444.248 108.547L271.254 8.76755C250.987 -2.92252 226.016 -2.92252 205.748 8.76755L32.7544 108.547C12.487 120.237 0 141.84 0 165.22V364.779C0 388.159 12.487 409.763 32.7544 421.453L205.748 521.232C226.016 532.923 250.987 532.923 271.254 521.232L444.248 421.453C464.516 409.763 477 388.159 477 364.779V165.22C477 141.84 464.516 120.237 444.248 108.547Z");
    clip-path: path("M444.248 108.547L271.254 8.76755C250.987 -2.92252 226.016 -2.92252 205.748 8.76755L32.7544 108.547C12.487 120.237 0 141.84 0 165.22V364.779C0 388.159 12.487 409.763 32.7544 421.453L205.748 521.232C226.016 532.923 250.987 532.923 271.254 521.232L444.248 421.453C464.516 409.763 477 388.159 477 364.779V165.22C477 141.84 464.516 120.237 444.248 108.547Z");
    height: 530px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 477px
}

.workaround>div:nth-child(2) {
    bottom: -32px;
    height: 594px;
    right: -32px;
    width: 541px
}

.workaround>div:nth-child(3) {
    bottom: -48px;
    height: 626px;
    right: -48px;
    width: 573px
}

.workaround>div:nth-child(4) {
    bottom: -64px;
    height: 658px;
    right: -64px;
    width: 605px
}

.workaround>div:nth-child(5) {
    bottom: -80px;
    height: 690px;
    right: -80px;
    width: 637px
}

.workaround>div:nth-child(6) {
    bottom: -96px;
    height: 722px;
    right: -96px;
    width: 669px
}
```

```html
<div class="workaround">
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have path already so you can use the same path for all visuals.

**One path** for the background image. But you need apply your image via "pattern" instead of css, see the example below.

**+1 Path** for each box shadow piece.

You can use path "stroke" property instead of box shadow. If you need real box shadow but not stroke you can use *"filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7));"* for each path. But I do not recommend it.

All of the paths in the example are exactly the same path. Just some properties changed.

You'll understand the logic when you look at the stroke colors and "stroke-widths".
**it's actually pretty simple.**

```html
<svg width="600" height="660" viewBox="0 0 600 660" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="imgpattern" width="1" height="1">
        <image xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/sJL6EDG.jpeg" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <path d="M505.248 173.547L332.254 73.7676C311.987 62.0775 287.016 62.0775 266.748 73.7676L93.7544 173.547C73.487 185.237 61 206.84 61 230.22V429.779C61 453.159 73.487 474.763 93.7544 486.453L266.748 586.232C287.016 597.923 311.987 597.923 332.254 586.232L505.248 486.453C525.516 474.763 538 453.159 538 429.779V230.22C538 206.84 525.516 185.237 505.248 173.547Z" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="60"/>
    <path d="M505.248 173.547L332.254 73.7676C311.987 62.0775 287.016 62.0775 266.748 73.7676L93.7544 173.547C73.487 185.237 61 206.84 61 230.22V429.779C61 453.159 73.487 474.763 93.7544 486.453L266.748 586.232C287.016 597.923 311.987 597.923 332.254 586.232L505.248 486.453C525.516 474.763 538 453.159 538 429.779V230.22C538 206.84 525.516 185.237 505.248 173.547Z" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="50"/>
    <path d="M505.248 173.547L332.254 73.7676C311.987 62.0775 287.016 62.0775 266.748 73.7676L93.7544 173.547C73.487 185.237 61 206.84 61 230.22V429.779C61 453.159 73.487 474.763 93.7544 486.453L266.748 586.232C287.016 597.923 311.987 597.923 332.254 586.232L505.248 486.453C525.516 474.763 538 453.159 538 429.779V230.22C538 206.84 525.516 185.237 505.248 173.547Z" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="48"/>
    <path d="M505.248 173.547L332.254 73.7676C311.987 62.0775 287.016 62.0775 266.748 73.7676L93.7544 173.547C73.487 185.237 61 206.84 61 230.22V429.779C61 453.159 73.487 474.763 93.7544 486.453L266.748 586.232C287.016 597.923 311.987 597.923 332.254 586.232L505.248 486.453C525.516 474.763 538 453.159 538 429.779V230.22C538 206.84 525.516 185.237 505.248 173.547Z" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="38"/>
    <path d="M505.248 173.547L332.254 73.7676C311.987 62.0775 287.016 62.0775 266.748 73.7676L93.7544 173.547C73.487 185.237 61 206.84 61 230.22V429.779C61 453.159 73.487 474.763 93.7544 486.453L266.748 586.232C287.016 597.923 311.987 597.923 332.254 586.232L505.248 486.453C525.516 474.763 538 453.159 538 429.779V230.22C538 206.84 525.516 185.237 505.248 173.547Z" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="36"/>
    <path d="M505.248 173.547L332.254 73.7676C311.987 62.0775 287.016 62.0775 266.748 73.7676L93.7544 173.547C73.487 185.237 61 206.84 61 230.22V429.779C61 453.159 73.487 474.763 93.7544 486.453L266.748 586.232C287.016 597.923 311.987 597.923 332.254 586.232L505.248 486.453C525.516 474.763 538 453.159 538 429.779V230.22C538 206.84 525.516 185.237 505.248 173.547Z" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="26"/>
    <path d="M505.248 173.547L332.254 73.7676C311.987 62.0775 287.016 62.0775 266.748 73.7676L93.7544 173.547C73.487 185.237 61 206.84 61 230.22V429.779C61 453.159 73.487 474.763 93.7544 486.453L266.748 586.232C287.016 597.923 311.987 597.923 332.254 586.232L505.248 486.453C525.516 474.763 538 453.159 538 429.779V230.22C538 206.84 525.516 185.237 505.248 173.547Z" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="24"/>
    <path d="M505.248 173.547L332.254 73.7676C311.987 62.0775 287.016 62.0775 266.748 73.7676L93.7544 173.547C73.487 185.237 61 206.84 61 230.22V429.779C61 453.159 73.487 474.763 93.7544 486.453L266.748 586.232C287.016 597.923 311.987 597.923 332.254 586.232L505.248 486.453C525.516 474.763 538 453.159 538 429.779V230.22C538 206.84 525.516 185.237 505.248 173.547Z" stroke="#FF0000" stroke-width="14"/>
    <path d="M505.248 173.547L332.254 73.7676C311.987 62.0775 287.016 62.0775 266.748 73.7676L93.7544 173.547C73.487 185.237 61 206.84 61 230.22V429.779C61 453.159 73.487 474.763 93.7544 486.453L266.748 586.232C287.016 597.923 311.987 597.923 332.254 586.232L505.248 486.453C525.516 474.763 538 453.159 538 429.779V230.22C538 206.84 525.516 185.237 505.248 173.547Z" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="12"/>
    <path d="M505.248 173.547L332.254 73.7676C311.987 62.0775 287.016 62.0775 266.748 73.7676L93.7544 173.547C73.487 185.237 61 206.84 61 230.22V429.779C61 453.159 73.487 474.763 93.7544 486.453L266.748 586.232C287.016 597.923 311.987 597.923 332.254 586.232L505.248 486.453C525.516 474.763 538 453.159 538 429.779V230.22C538 206.84 525.516 185.237 505.248 173.547Z" stroke="#FF0000" stroke-width="2"/>
    <path d="M505.248 173.547L332.254 73.7676C311.987 62.0775 287.016 62.0775 266.748 73.7676L93.7544 173.547C73.487 185.237 61 206.84 61 230.22V429.779C61 453.159 73.487 474.763 93.7544 486.453L266.748 586.232C287.016 597.923 311.987 597.923 332.254 586.232L505.248 486.453C525.516 474.763 538 453.159 538 429.779V230.22C538 206.84 525.516 185.237 505.248 173.547Z" fill="url(#imgpattern)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: It's still got some visual artefacts, see https://prnt.sc/jAn_TON28FXw, but good solution nonetheless. I'll give you the bounty, thanks